# JQuery not working on a Job Adder JS Widget

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site http://www.nicherecruitment.co.nz/hr/job-search/?ja-classifications=319121

Basically, what I need is if I hit the '**More**' or the job heading, they go to the actual link (e.g `http://www.nicherecruitment.co.nz/hr/job-search/?ja-job=1566592`)

The default is when I click read more (or heading), the job details will just expand, the link is not changing. That prevents the user to reference the actual link of a job.

I tried jquery code to change the `href` attribute but its strange its not working. It doesn't effect at all:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.job a.view-details').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href',"<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?ja-    job="+$(this).attr('data-job-id'));
    });
    console.log("<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>");
    console.log($('.job a.view-details').attr('data-job-id'));

    $('.job a.view-details').addClass('testClass');
    $('.job .view-details').hide();

});
```

The first console log outputs the necessary permalink I need to output `http://www.nicherecruitment.co.nz/hr/job-search/`. 
The second is to output attr with the name data-job-id but it outputs 'undefined'

The addClass() and hide() is just to test if my codes affect the target. But none of them affects the target.

I also tried an alternative solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( "body" ).on( "click", ".job a.view-details", function() {
    $(this).preventDefault();    
       var url = "<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?ja-job=" + $(this).attr('data-job-id');
       window.location.replace(url);
  });
}); 

</script>
```

Expected output: 

    `After someone has clicked anywhere in the body, jquery looks at all the elements on the     page again (so the dynamic content we added gets included in the DOM) it then see's if the click was on the view-details link. If it was, it prevents the link from working (preventDefault) and executes our code`

But that's not the case, its does nothing at all :(.

The **Job Adder JS Widget** code is:

```
<div id="ja-jobs-widget"></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
    var _jaJobsSettings = {                         
       key: "3hmt352pjc3exomgzmpysvycpm",                         
       applicationFormSettings: { 
            useExternalApplicationForm: true,                    
            showExternalApplicationFormInNewWindow: false                         
       },                                       
       jobSearchSettings: {             
            showSearchForm: true,           
            searchButtonText: "Search"              
       }             
    };
// ]]></script>
 <script src="//jobadder.com/widgets/v1/jobs.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use event delegation. Appears your data is being loaded via ajax so those elements don't exist when your code runs

Comment: @charlietfl: Im not very familiar with event delegation. Any suggestion, link, article, etc that best to apply in this case?

Comment: thousands of posts on this site about it. Also find tons of info in google search. Start by reading jQuery docs for `on()` and look for the event delgation usage

Comment: @charlietfl: I already tried some event delegation. But does not work at all. Any suggestion? I already edit the post.

Comment: show the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread was solved by my colleague.

For the benefit of others here who are also beginners, here's the code that I wanna share:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(function ($) {

            $( document ).on( "mouseenter", "#ja-jobs-widget", function(e) {

                $('.job a.view-details').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('href',"<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>?ja-job="+$(this).attr('data-job-id'));
                    $(this).removeClass('view-details');
                });

             });
   });

</script>
```

"We use the 'on' function, for when content has been dynamically added to the DOM, so content that wasn't there on page load, but was added dynamically by the JobAdder Javascript.

It just loops through each of the links and changes the href attribute.

It then removes the 'view-details' class so JobAdder doesn't override our link and so next time the mouse enters the div, it doesn't keep looping through this" -

Answer (score 0):

The mix jQuery/PHP looks like fail.

That `get_permalink()` should be a data attribute of your `.job a.view-details`, as it wont work "on the fly". Once the HTML is rendered, we don't have dynamic access to PHP functions, only through AJAX.